# psgraph scale description doesn't work

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I've got a small problem. I don't can set the right scale description. Please, have a look at this code:

```
\def\data1{
    % x (degree) % y1 % y2
0 8188 7538
15 9143 8464
30 9605 9075
45 9564 9277
60 9047 9074
75 8044 8477
90 6653 7838
} 
\begin{psgraph}[Dx=90, dx=0, Dy=10000, dy=2000, arrows=->](0,0)(0,0)(10,10){0.5\textwidth}{!}
        \pstScalePoints(1,1){10 div}{1000 div}
        \listplot[plotstyle=curve, linecolor=blue, plotNo=1, plotNoMax=2]{\data1}
        \listplot[plotstyle=curve, linecolor=red, plotNo=2, plotNoMax=2]{\data1}
         \pstScalePoints(1,1){}{}
\end{psgraph}
```

I need the x-Axis from 0 to 90 degrees and the y-axis from 2000 to 10000. What's wrong?

Thanks

Teskania

Comment: FYI: This is a crosspost to the german forum [goLaTeX](http://www.golatex.de/achsenskalierung-bei-psgraph-anpassen-t13232.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no real sense to have the y axis up to 10000, use a bigger value. However here is the solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\def\data1{
    % x (degree) % y1 % y2
0 8188 7538
15 9143 8464
30 9605 9075
45 9564 9277
60 9047 9074
75 8044 8477
90 6653 7838
} 
\begin{psgraph}[Dx=10,dx=1,ylabelFactor=\cdot10^3,Dy=2,Oy=2,arrows=->](0,0)(9,9){0.5\textwidth}{!}
        \pstScalePoints(1,1){10 div}{1000 div}
        \listplot[plotstyle=curve, linecolor=blue, plotNo=1, plotNoMax=2]{\data1}
        \listplot[plotstyle=curve, linecolor=red, plotNo=2, plotNoMax=2]{\data1}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

- `Dx=10, dx=1` every x unit an incrment of 10
- `Dy=2, Oy=2` every 2 y units an increment of 2 beginning at 2 (without setting `dx` it is always like `Dx`